# Fejer Kernel (Time Series)

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I encountered this in my notes:

$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathcal{F}(f- f')df = 1\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
where
$$\mathcal{F}(f) = \frac{\sin^2(N\pi f)}{N \sin^2(\pi f)}$$

I know that 
$$\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathcal{F}(f)df = 1$$

But I do not know how $(1)$ comes about. I mean how does it integrate to $1$? Please give me a hand here plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{F}$ is a periodic function with periodicity of $1$. So it wouldn't matter which value you are using for $f'$.

Comment: can frequency $f'$ be 0.5, 0.75 ...? OR does it have to take integer values ???

Comment: $f'$ can be any real values.

Comment: do u mind illustrating what you mean by "periodicity of 1" please ?

Comment: I suppose $N$ is an integer. Then $\frac{\sin^2(N\pi(x+1))}{\sin^2(\pi(x+1))} = \frac{\sin^2(N\pi x)}{\sin^2(\pi x)}$